# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES error in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I have made a PhoneGap/Cordova based application, that seems to work fine when tested with Chrome + Ripple.

When I'm trying to install it to my Android device(which is ADB configured, and shows up in Eclipse SDK), I get the INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES error.

By reading existing posts on the same issue, I understand that it has to deal with re-installation of the app.

But, this is the first time I am trying to run this app on any device, and I don't see how re-installing might solve the problem.

Any advice on resolving the error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look for another app in settings->apps->downloaded that may have the same package name and uninstall it.